# How to create an application in Nx that has no pre-existing generator?

Tags: vuejs3, monorepo

The various community Vue application generators for Nx will not work for me, so I'd like to start a new ***empty*** app in Nx. But it seems a pre-existing generator is always required (?). When I don't specify one, it defaults to @nrwl/web:application.

Ideally I have an empty app in which I can run "`pnpm create vuetify`", and set it up from there. This always provides a very solid foundation for my Vue/Vuetify apps.

I must be missing something, Nx claims to be able to hold any kind of software project, but the list of application generators is really limited.